# Python change listbox colors in real time

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Win7, Python 2.7, Tkinter

I have several list boxes on the screen at once, and I am setting up a way to let the user change the colors (background, text color, border width, border color, etc...) There are more then just list boxes, there are label frames, progress bars, window frames, to name a few.

The listbox (and other widgets) labels are declared in a globals file, thuis:

```
globs.lb1 = tk.Listbox(root, ...
```

I can change the attributes easily enough, but what is the best method to update all the widgets?

Currently, in my Settings.py file, I am manually setting each list box, (and other widgets) but, or course, if I add a widget later, I must remember to change the Settings.py file.

I would like to use ttk, I think ttk allows me to change the style, then ttk will remember which widgets use that style, but there is no Listbox in ttk.

If there were an event or something of that nature I could setup for each list box...

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: define a subclass of Listbox that registers each listbox you create so that when a user changes settings, you can iterater through the set/list of listboxes.

Option 2: use a ttk.Combobox or a ttk.Treeview (with only top-level items and not expansion for subitems).  I think one could think of a treeview as a supercharged listbox, with multiple columns and possible hierarchical relationships.

Comment: Damn Terry, that was fast. I think I get it, I can make a global list with the list boxes (other widgets) labels as entries in the list, then simply do a for i in range(len(global_list)): ... I like it. Thanks.

Comment: Even better: `for widget in registered_widgets: repaint(widget)`.  I may eventually face this same issue with IDLE.  Users can customize editor Text widgets (which includes the shell), but not anything else.  I could consider Option 1, but have other priorities.  I will wait until Option 2 is possible. We are starting to use ttk widgets.  When the conversion is complete, and I learn to use customized styles, I might consider dialog customization via styles